# The method to save the training time in keras LSTM/CuDNNLSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

Here is my code of `LSTM` in `keras`. Is there any method/property of `LSTM` can be used to largely improve the training speed (we are allowed to cut a part of performance to improve the speed). For example, `MLP` in `sklearn` we can set small `max_iter` or `early_stopping=True` to save the training time. I am not familiar with `keras` `CuDNNLSTM/LSTM`, not sure which property I can use.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, input_shape=(array_X_train.shape[1], array_X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation ='tanh'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
model.fit(array_X_train, array_Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=1, verbose=2,
         callbacks=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss"))
```